# Meteor Loading an external JS file upon .created event for all the app templates

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an external JS file which I need to load upon the create event for all my Meteor app templates. As far as I have read Meteor will ignore the  tags found in my template html but I can't figure out how to load this external JS file from the template.created event? and if there is anyway I can do this for all app templates without having to replicate code across all templates .created event? Thanks

Comment: If its loaded for every template why not just include it in the normal app JS bundle?

Comment: @sbking Can you please explain how to include it in the 'normal app JS bundle'? Thanks

Comment: Just add it to the `/client` or `/client/compatibility` directory ([depending on your needs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)) in your Meteor application. Then Meteor will bundle it in with all the other client JS files it sends.